# JS не определяет элемент path внутри svg

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, svg

Я пишу сервис бронирования мест в зале.
Есть следующие файлы:

**index.php**

```
        ...
        <!-- Див, где появляется схема зала -->
        <div id="draggable-frame" class="content-seatscheme">

        </div>
        <script>
            //вывести схему зала по ссылке seatschemes_url (svg)
            $(".content-seatscheme").load(seatschemes_url);

            //из sessions_seatsoccupied пометить занятые места (места в формате "rX-sX")
            //выполнить по загрузке svg
            $(document).ready(function () {
                let occupied_seats = sessions_seatsoccupied.split(",");
                console.log(occupied_seats);
                for (let i = 0; i < occupied_seats.length; i++) {
                    let seat = occupied_seats[i].split("-");
                    console.log(seat);
                    let row = seat[0].split("r")[1];
                    let seat_number = seat[1].split("s")[1];
                    console.log(row);
                    console.log(seat_number);
                    //пометить место как занятое внутри svg у кружка, у которого id = "rX-sX" через attr
                    $("#r" + row + "-s" + seat_number).attr("class", "occupied");
                }
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .occupied {
                stroke: #990000;
                stroke-opacity: 0.7;
                stroke-width: 2;
            }
        </style>
        ...
```

**scheme.svg (для примера)**

```
<svg id="scheme" width="540" height="362" viewBox="0 0 540 362" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path id="r1-s1 v" d="M25 104.5C25 100.358 28.3579 97 32.5 97C36.6421 97 40 100.358 40 104.5C40 108.642 36.6421 112 32.5 112C28.3579 112 25 108.642 25 104.5Z" fill="#E18700"/></svg>
```

На вход в seatschemes_url подаётся ссылка на scheme.svg, в sessions_seatsoccupied подаётся r1-s1. Свгшка успешно загружается, появляется кружок, но скрипт почему-то не помечает его как занятый, соответственно класс occupied на нём не появляется.

Проверил в консоли браузера, может ли он обнаружить этот path с id="r1-s1 v" внутри svg. При вводе document.querySelector("#r1-s1"); появляется надпись null. Как мне сделать скрипт исправным, и чтобы кружок отметился занятым?

Comment: Если что, jquery подключен, и svg прогружается корректно на страницу.

Comment: Так у вас id='r1-s1 v' а вы ищите по(условно) 'r1-s1'

Comment: Так v это второй айдишник. Он к данному вопросу вообще никакого отношения не имеет. Но если вам интересно что это за буква, то она обозначает тип места. Но повторюсь, меня волнует первый айдишник.

Comment: У HTML элементов один ID. Нет такоко - второй ID. ID это строка и в данном случае, это 'r1-s1 v'. Либо добавляйте ' v' к ID для поиска, либо выносите в другой аттрибут, допустим data-*

Comment: Хорошо, вы мне открыли глаза по одному айди))) Был неправ) Но это ничего не меняет, всё равно если убрать эту буковку v, то path не найдётся

Comment: Выведите в консоль `"#r" + row + "-s" + seat_number`, так же в браузере посмотрите, что у вас есть path с таким ID (нет лишних пробелов). Я у себя пробовал, все прекрасно находит(правда без jquery)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, добрый человек) Это я дурачина, думал что в id можно поместить два названия, поэтому оно и не работало. Вопрос закрыт

Comment: Нет, ID это одно уникальное значение(строка) и все ) Хорошо, что разобрались!